# Misunderstanding the proper use of Input Text value Property function

Tags: javascript

I am working my way through a small learning exercise in Javascript that gets the value of text in a text area and replaces the single quotes with double quotes as indicated by the regex.   What I am confused about is why I can't/don't/ shouldn't include the "value" property" in the argument passed to the replaceQuote() function.

In the code below i pass document.form1.textarea1, and all works well.   If I modify the function to pass the argument as document.form1.textarea1.value, the code doesn't work.

My question is this, what am I clearly misunderstanding about value property and how it functions.   I am pretty sure it's something very fundamental that I am just too obtuse to "get"

This version of the function works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function replaceQuote(textarea) {
         var myText = textarea.value;
         var myRegExp = /\B'|'\B/g;
         myText = myText.replace(myRegExp,'"')
         textarea.value = myText;
     }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name = "form1">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="40" name="textarea1">
        'Hello World' said Mr O'Connerly.
He then said 'My Name is O'Connerly, yes that's right, O'Connerly'.
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="replace single quote" onclick="replaceQuote(document.form1.textarea1)">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This version of the function does not work.  Function is modified to accept replaceQuote(document.form1.textarea1.value)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function replaceQuote(textarea) {
             var myText = textarea;
             var myRegExp = /\B'|'\B/g;
             myText = myText.replace(myRegExp,'"')
             textarea = myText;
         }

     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name = "form1">
        <textarea rows="20" cols="40" name="textarea1">
            'Hello World' said Mr O'Connerly.
    He then said 'My Name is O'Connerly, yes that's right, O'Connerly'.
        </textarea>
        <input type="button" value="replace single quote" onclick="replaceQuote(document.form1.textarea1.value)">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your picture is wild!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, a reference to the actual `textarea` object is being passed in.  That means you can both read and write the `.value` property of the `textarea`.

In the second version, just the value of the `.value` property is being passed in - ie the actual contents of the text area.  Within the function, it's just a local variable containing text, so assigning `myText` to it has no effect outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second version of your code does not work is because in the `replaceQuotes` function when you wrote

`textarea = myText;`

`textarea` is a local variable that has the value of the text in the textarea.